# Regex em XML do word

Tags: javascript, xml, regex

Tenho um xml que veio de um docx nesse formato:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00AE2D8E" w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E" w:rsidRDefault="00AE2D8E">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>amet</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>consecteur</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>.</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

O que está escrito no docx é "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur.", porém ele acaba quebrando por conta das diferenças de fonte, bold, etc.

O problema é que eu preciso substituir o texto "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur." por outro qualquer.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso pelo regex? É possível? Se não, qual outra opção viável?

EDIT:
Então, meu objetivo é substituir o texto "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur." por outro texto. O problema é que no meio dele, por conta do xml do docx, são criadas tags de orientação da formatação do texto (, ). O regex que tenho aqui é:

```
\bLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur.\b
```

Esse regex acaba não encontrando a frase por conta dos códigos no meio, o ideal é que ele substituísse ignorando os códigos no meio.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, se editar e explicar melhor tento te ajudar!

Comment: Ok, editei tentando explicar melhor.

Comment: Notei que o texto está fragmentado em algumas tags. Poderia eliminar todas essas tags onde tem texto e deixar apenas uma?

Comment: Veja como ficaria: https://jsfiddle.net/n7oLhfk3/

Comment: Acho que não vai rolar, imagina em um documento grande e com várias partes, preciso dar um replace em várias partes. Explicando de uma maneira geral, preciso traduzir partes de um docx.

Comment: Vc quer eliminar as tags e pegar apenas o texto e substituir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor maneira de capturar um texto no caso do seu XML é usando as tags de abrir e fechar como delimitador de captura, ou seja, capturar qualquer coisa que esteja fora das tags, iniciando a captura em qualquer caractere a partir do fechamento da tag `>` e delimitando a captura até a abertura de uma outra tag `<`.

A regex a seguir faz exatamente isso:

```
>([A-zÀ-ÿ.,:?! ]{1,})<|>([ A-zÀ-ÿ.,:?!]{1,})\n
```

Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/bqqFQb/2).

Explicação da regex:

- `>([A-zÀ-ÿ.,:?! ]{1,})<` - delimita que a regex iniciará a captura a partir do caractere `<`, a partir daí temos um grupo de captura `([A-zÀ-ÿ]{1,})`, ele irá capturar 1 ou mais letras, números, espaços ou pontuação, desde que esses caracteres tenham em seguida a abertura de outra tag ou seja até `<`
- `|` - é um operador OR, ele indica que essa regex pode aceitar o padrão anterior ou o padrão depois do delimitador
- `>([ A-zÀ-ÿ.,:?!]{1,})\n` - faz a mesma coisa que o grupo 1, porém o delimitador dele é a quebra de linha, pra casos onde o texto seja a última coisa da linha até a abertura da tag na linha seguinte.

Comment: Ainda esperando o comentário de quem negativou justificando o ato...

Comment: Cara, acho que consigo fazer funcionar com isso.

Comment: Sabe me dizer porque não pegou o trecho "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"

Comment: sim, porque esqueci de colocar nas possibilidades de captura o espaço, vou atualizar a resposta e o link de teste da regex

Comment: @Juliano editado

Comment: @Juliano me avise se funcionou ou se vai precisar de mais ajuda ;)

Comment: Desculpe... só tive tempo agora, a solução funcionou, obrigado.